# What is the meaning of these numbers in Simulink?

Tags: simulink

Consider following parts of a Simulink model. (Note that I removed the content of the blocks.)

[image]

I want to know the meaning of the numbers

- above and below the arrows: 14{14}, 25, [25x121]
- in the top right-hand side of the blocks: 0:B, 0:8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `14{14}`, `25` and `[25x121]` above the signals are the signal dimensions:

- In the case of `25`, it's a single vector signal of width `25`;
- In the case of `[25x121]`, it's a matrix signal of dimensions `[25x121]`;
- In the case of `14{14}`, it's a bus signal with 14 signals carried in the bus and 14 signal elements carried in the bus (i.e. each signal is of width 1)

Consider the following example in the [Simulink documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/displaying-signal-properties.html):

[image]

For the other numbers inside the block, they represent the sorted execution order of the model, i.e. in which order each block gets executed. It's difficult to explain what each number is without seeing the whole of the model and copying the documentation verbatim (the notation changes depending on what type of block it is and its level in the model hierarchy) , so I'll just refer you to the [documentation page](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/controlling-and-displaying-the-sorted-order.html), which should provide all the necessary explanations.

Comment: And what about `0:11{145}` in the right-hand upper corner of a (`switch`) block?

Comment: Again, difficult to say without seeing the model, but probably a combination of sorted order and signal dimensions. Try turning the display off one at a time to see the effect on the model.